# Android : Click event is not triggered at time of animation

Tags: android, animation

I have a Button. On click of button i animate the TextView.

At the time of animation click is not working for texview.

```
 buttonclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           final Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 10.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 10.0f);
            animation.setDuration(100000);
            textView.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    });


    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: what you mean with "at time"? doesn´t it work at all or does it animate with delay?

Comment: when the animation is done, the click is not working?

Comment: It works before animation start. but when animation starts the click of textview is not working.

Comment: @Luiz not that is not issue

Comment: I have to click on textview when animation is going on.

Comment: what´s the minTarget and maxTarget you are developing on?

Comment: API min 16 and max is 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Animation`s are only *animating* views, not changing, its an *illusion*... You are using  `TranslateAnimation`, so you are moving your views "look", not the view itself. Ewentually you may use `setFillAfter(true)` method, then `View` will be clickable AFTER animation end (but your anim is long/infinite...).

Consider using `Animator` instead, which is changing "parameters" (in your case real position) of view with every frame of anim

```
ObjectAnimator animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "x", newx);
ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "y", newy);
AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
animSetXY.playTogether(animX, animY);
animSetXY.start();
```

Comment: Is it possible to click view when animation is going on?

Comment: nope, when you are animating then you are just changing "look" of this item. it is still clickable in place where it was added on start, not where the "look" is drawn (animated and placed somewhere else on screen). This is the main difference between `Animation` and `Animator` - in many cases you just need short anim of view without interaction (at all or at least during anim) and for this purposes is `Animation` (more efficient than `Animator` - not changing "real" attributes of `View`, just draw/change `Bitmap` of `View` withour re-measuring all `View`s in layout)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
PropertyValuesHolder x = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", 50f);
PropertyValuesHolder y = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", 100f);
ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(mTextView, x, y).start();
```

this way, you can animate whole view object--not just the contents.